# Move email to another folder with OpenPop

Tags: c#, openpop

How I can to move emails from **inbox** to some folder, for example folder "**test**"

```
Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client()
```

client contains method to get email in **html**, **xml**, etc. also **delete email or delete all emails**, but I need to move some email to another folder, it is possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067618/does-the-pop3-protocol-support-a-folder-system

Comment: If possible why not use rules? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-50307363-0e79-4f6a-95c0-04b922a2ff13?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US

Answer (score 2):

OpenPop implements the POP3 protocol. This protocol is old, and does not know about such things as `folders`. Therefore, the OpenPop implementation cannot handle folders as well.

If you need to use folders, consider using some IMAP client instead. IMAP is a newer and more modern protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As J. Steen has pointed out. No, you can't with OpenPop.

Just encase you still want to do it and it wasn't a purely academic question. Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268996.aspx)

**How to: Programmatically Move Items in Outlook**

This example moves unread e-mail messages from the Inbox to a folder named Test. The example only moves messages that have the word Test in the Subject field.

Applies to: The information in this topic applies to application-level projects for Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2010. For more information, see Features Available by Office Application and Project Type.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
        ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler
        (ThisAddIn_NewMail);
}

private void ThisAddIn_NewMail()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)this.Application.
        ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items items = (Outlook.Items)inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem moveMail = null;
    items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = inBox.Folders["Test"];
    foreach (object eMail in items)
    {
        try
        {
            moveMail = eMail as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (moveMail != null)
            {
                string titleSubject = (string)moveMail.Subject;
                if (titleSubject.IndexOf("Test") > 0)
                {
                    moveMail.Move(destFolder);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```